# What's the minimum possible mass of a stable neutron star?

Tags: mass, astrophysics, stability, neutron-stars

What's the minimum possible mass of a stable neutron star?
Let's say you have a neutron star and slowly take away it's mass, e.g., either by firing a stream of anti-neutrons or by proton decay, since neutrons stars do contain protons in their crust.

And what mass would it stop being a neutron star and what would happen to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the theoretical lower mass limit for a gravitationally stable neutron star?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143166/)

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409193/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273175/123208